# Is it possible to add an alternate searchable text in Select2?

Tags: jquery-select2

is it possible to search an alternate text in select2?, my select2 contains the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "text": "London"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "text": "New York"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "text": "Tokyo"
  }
]
```

I'm thinking about how to add another alternate text (in my case it's alternate_text below so I would also able to search CC-910 and it will shows New York)

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "text": "London",
    "alternate_text": "CC-123"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "text": "New York",
    "alternate_text": "CC-901",

  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "text": "Tokyo",
    "alternate_text": "CC-678"
  }
]
```

Any body can give me an idea how to accomplish this?

many thanks
Doy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to place the alternative text you want to search in a hidden span and override the escapeMarkup option to not escape the html markings.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
const data = [
  {
    "id": 10,
    "text": "London <span style='display: none;'>CC-123</span>"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "text": "New York<span style='display: none;'>CC-901</span>"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "text": "Tokyo<span style='display: none;'>CC-678</span>"
  }
];

  $('#item_box').select2({data: data, escapeMarkup: (text) => text}); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="item_box" style="width: 100%;"></select>
```